# Channel Forms Upload Image missing directory info

Tags: safecracker, file-uploads

I have a channel form I am trying to get working. There is a file upload which looks like this.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="story_image">Upload a picture</label>
  <div id="story_image" class="btn btn-gray-light btn-file">
    <span class="feedback">Choose a file: </span>   
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="story_image">
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="story_image_directory" value="13">
  <input type="hidden" id="story_image_hidden_file" name="story_image_hidden_file" value="">

  <p class="help-block">Image size should be no larger than 800px square and no larger than 2mb.</p>
</div>
```

Then when I check the entry I see the following.

```
{filedir_13}tumblr_n4z1wlApId1sljr6oo1_500.jpg
```

I can use the {field:story_image} and the upload will work correctly, but for some reason when I strip out all the extra markup it's broken. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

From memory, I think you have to add square brackets after the file field like this

```
<input type="file" name="my_field_name[]" />
```

**UPDATE:**
Also the docs say to format the hidden file like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_field_name_hidden_file" value="{my_field_name}{file_name}{/my_field_name}" />
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to work. I am still getting the {filedir_13} before the file name and the file not being uploaded.

Comment: You confident the actual ID of the upload directory is 13 ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with a jQuery conflict. I had 1.9.x and that was causing an error. Once I put the jQuery in the header and included it in the script it works fine. It's disappointing that this has to be set up this way given that most people put JS in their footer and jQuery 1.8.3 is ancient.

Oh, well. At least I got it working.